# How to specify the name of file you create in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a file in javascript. Before you say that it is impossible, go read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178825/create-text-file-in-javascript).

Here is what I have so far :

```
window.open("data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + escape("Ur String Object goes here"));
```

Now, my question is : How do I give a name to this file?

Comment: that's not a file. you're just passing around a STRING. a filename would only come into play if the user did a file->save as in that window

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717851/save-file-javascript-with-file-name

Comment: @epascarello Oh fine then.

Answer (score 1):

You don't; data URIs don't have a filename:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Disadvantages

You can link to it and use the `download` attribute, though:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

FWIW, you're not really creating a file here.