# How to capture file name and add it inside of a text file

Tags: javascript, ruby, text-files

I have an input to load files and  JavaScript code to get the file name, that I found here on Stack Overflow:

My input:

```
<%= file_field_tag 'file' %>
```

The JavaScript code:

```
var fullPath = document.getElementById('file').value;
if (fullPath) {
   var startIndex = (fullPath.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? fullPath.lastIndexOf('\\') : fullPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
   var filename = fullPath.substring(startIndex);
   if (filename.indexOf('\\') === 0 || filename.indexOf('/') === 0) {
      filename = filename.substring(1);
   }
   alert(filename);
}
```

Instead of turn it into an `alert(filename)`, is there a way to make it save the file name into a text file?

Comment: Where do you want the text file? In the server or the clients browser?

Comment: It is going to be saved locally, there will be a link to a history page and there the user will be able to access his history

Comment: You could use the method proposed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178825/create-text-file-in-javascript).

Comment: Please don't use "edit" tags when editing your text. Instead, incorporate the new information into your question as if it'd been there initially. We can tell what changed if we need to look at the revision logs.

Comment: Ah thanks for the tip