# Javascript: serve text as a file

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save file Javascript with file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717851/save-file-javascript-with-file-name)

In javascript I have some data in a variable that I would like to give to the user as a file. How could I go about doing this?

**Duplicate** of [Save file Javascript with file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717851/save-file-javascript-with-file-name), sorry.

Comment: As a file what do you mean by that ? Do you want your user to be able to download that text in a variable as a text file ??

Comment: this may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392117/how-to-create-save-a-txt-file-with-javascript-compatible-cross-browser

Comment: I think this is close to what you want to do 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717851/save-file-javascript-with-file-name

Comment: @MimiEAM Brilliant. Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @devundef I'm sorry, a lot of my questions are a bit poor, so there really are no answers. Thank you for pointing it out, though.